# SharePoint designer WF with 2010 template

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have 7 If... else conditions on a SPD workflow (2010 template) in SharePoint online. Now I will have to change it to 28 if ... else conditions. I was not able to find anywhere if there is a limit of the if ... else or not and what is this limit.

See below a sample of the first 2 IFs
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint Limitations – Workflow Limit Maximum value](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/11/01/sharepoint-limitations-workflow-limit-maximum-value/)

No limit is conditions, limit is value!